# Transpile custom JSX tag to custom function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

React's JSX transpiler converts a tag:

```
<MyComponent />
```

to:

```
React.createElement("MyComponent");
```

---

I need to develop something so that when using a `tag`:

```
<TagFunction msg={varMessage} />
```

It is converted to:

```
function() { alert(varMessage); }
```

---

It sounds strange, but this is a simplified example of the real need.

Would it be possible to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Custom Component this way:

```js
const CustomComponent = (props) => {
   const { varMessage } = props;
   alert(varMessage);
   return null;
}
```

Then use it like this:

```js
<CustomComponent varMessage="my message" />
```

You can define a varMessage variable and pass it to the `varMessage` prop too!

Comment: I really need this to be done on the transpiler. I need it to actually become a function, rather than a React component.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you need a way to execute some code when you render a tag. I am assuming you would want to run that piece of code only once or on certain conditions change

IF you use hooks you could implement it as a simple component and add the logic in useEffect

```
const LogicComponent = ({msg}) => {
   useEffect(() => {
         alert(msg)
   }, [msg])

   return null;
}
```

However if you don't use hooks, you will have to write a class component and implement its componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate lifecycles

```
class LogicComponent extends React.Component {
   componentDidMount() {
      this.myFunction();
   }

   componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      if(this.props.msg !== prevProps.msg) {
          this.myFunction()
      }
   }
   myFunction = () => {
      alert(this.props.msg)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not "easily" possible. You would have to write a custom JSX transpiler.

The JSX code is transpiled to Javascript by the plugin [plugin-transform-react-jsx](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx) [(create-plugin.ts)](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/main/packages/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx/src/create-plugin.ts). So the JSX code goes into the transpiler, and the Javascript with the
`React.createElement` ([or `_jsx`](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html), ...)
comes out. If you want to alter that, you need to do that inside the transpiler, or write your own transpliler.

To learn how to [develop an own babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#plugin-development) babel recommends the [babel-handbook](https://github.com/thejameskyle/babel-handbook).